# cannot set text input ref

Tags: react-native, react-hook-form, textinput

I'm trying to switch focus between inputs on `onSubmitEditing` but I can't manage to pass the ref props from my custom text input to the main component.

The console log I've put in the `ref` doesn't log anything.

```js
const MyCustomInput = (props) => {
    <View> 
        <FormInput
              {...props}
              editable={!props.disabled}
              selectTextOnFocus={!props.disabled}
              disable={props.disabled}
              displayOnly={props.displayOnly}
              small={props.small}
              placeholderTextColor={'#AFAFAF'}
         />
    </View>
}
```

```js
    <Controller
          control={control}
          render={({field: {onChange, onBlur, value, ref}}) => (
            <MyCustomInput
              onBlur={onBlur}
              onChangeText={(value: string) => onChange(value)}
              value={value}
              ref={(r: any) => {
                console.log('r', r);
                ref(r);
                inputRef.current = r;
              }}
            />
          )}
          name="myInput"
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I was missing a forward ref in my custom input

```js
const MyCustomInput = fowardRef((props, ref) => {
    <View> 
        <FormInput
              {...props}
              ref={ref}
              editable={!props.disabled}
              selectTextOnFocus={!props.disabled}
              disable={props.disabled}
              displayOnly={props.displayOnly}
              small={props.small}
              placeholderTextColor={'#AFAFAF'}
         />
    </View>
)}
```